# Can we use ng-repeat to create different Directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Think we have a few directives:
Directive1, Directive2, ...

I would like to us ng-repeat that gets array of these directives names and create each one of them.

Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible with `ng-repeat`. However there is no need to go `ng-repeat` way. You could declare an array on the controller scope and use the `$compile` service to create your directives.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.directiveArray = ['a', 'b ', 'c'];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.directiveArray.length; i++) {
    var dirName = $scope.directiveArray[i];
    var dirCompiled = $compile('<' + dirName + '></' + dirName + '>')($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('holder')).append(dirCompiled);
  }
});

app.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>I\'m a </div>'
  }
});

app.directive('b', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>I\'m b </div>'
  }
});

app.directive('c', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>I\'m c </div>'
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="holder"></div>
  </body>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8WMoJ3lMPs7fHEJnrEsL)**